# Getting arbitrary key/value parameters with Apache Commons CLI

Tags: java, apache-commons-cli

A framework I'm using (and can change if necessary, but would rather not) is using Apache Commons CLI. My application needs to acquire a series of well-defined arguments, but also in some cases accept a series of key/value pairs. These will eventually end up being injected into a Spring context that the application starts.

Any suggestions on the best way of getting a series of key/value pairs as one String option using Commons CLI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i would probably handle them as additional arbitrary strings via [CommandLine.getArgs()](http://commons.apache.org/cli/api-release/org/apache/commons/cli/CommandLine.html#getArgs%28%29). You then can still define all the default options and parse the key/value-pairs afterwards.